# Regex quantifiers are not working well with locate

Tags: debian, regular-expression, locate

This output is rather self-explanatory:

```
XXXXX@debianvirtualbox:~$ locate -r "^/var/lib/tomcat[0-9]/.*" -l 10
/var/lib/tomcat8/conf
/var/lib/tomcat8/lib
/var/lib/tomcat8/logs
/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps
/var/lib/tomcat8/work
/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/websight
/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/META-INF
/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/index.html
/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/META-INF/context.xml
jakub@maredadebianvirtualbox:~$ locate -r "^/var/lib/tomcat[0-9]{1,2}/.*" -l 10
XXXXX@debianvirtualbox:~$
```

I am trying to list first ten (`-l 10`) entries matching tomcat installation directory. If I just use `[0-9]` it properly matches `tomcat8`, however if I add a quantifier `[0-9]{1,2}` it matches nothing. Same goes for quantifiers `+` and `?`, however `*` seems to work fine and so does this expression:

```
^/var/lib/tomcat[0-9][0-9]*/.*
```

Why this happens and what's a good workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `--regex` (without a 'p') rather than `-r` (aka `--regexp`).  This tells `locate` to use extended regexps rather than basic.

```
locate --regex "^/var/lib/tomcat[0-9]{1,2}/" -l 10
```

alternatively, escape `{` and `}` with `\` to make them special in basic regex.

Comment: BTW, the above applies to mlocate's version of `locate`.  I can't remember if it also applies to GNU locate from findutils, I haven't used anything other than mlocate for years.

Comment: Yeah, it works even with normal locate, thanks.

Comment: GNU locate has a `--regextype` option to specify the type of regular expression.  http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Regular-Expressions